# How to duplicate a tag in Signal Data Hub

Tags: tags, signal, tracking

I have a couple of tags setup in Signal Data Hub and I would like to know, if it is possible to duplicate these tags. Meaning, I want to keep everything about the tags the same except how they are named, so that I can use both separately.

I have looked into their documentation but to no avail, perhaps I am trying the wrong approach here.

Comment: This appears to be some kind of web service. So it is off-topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill I asked on the stack exchange chat a while ago about *where* to ask and was referred to super user. Feel free to recommend where to ask or if this is even a question to ask on the stack exchange

Comment: If it **is** a web service (not clear from the company website - but if you are using it then you should know) then the question belongs on [WebApps.SE].

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks! I see you have a large reputation, is it possible for you to move this question there, or do I have to close this one and ask it on the other site?

Comment: Only mods can move questions. You can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it. They will do so if they feel the migration is appropriate.

Comment: It **may** be on-topic here - I'm unclear about that (because of my lack of specific knowledge about what Signal Data Hub actually is).

Comment: @DavidPostill I did flag it for moderator attention, they can better decide (hoping one comments here for the matter)

Comment: Before I migrate it, some more context would be nice - could you perhaps add a link to the application in question and documentation?

Comment: Users with 3,000 reputation can vote to migrate to Web Apps if they feel confident the question belongs on the destination. But where is the link to what Signal Data Hub is?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I cannot until tomorrow since the program is not available to me from where I currently am, thanks for the prompt response

Comment: @random will provide it in about 10 hours.